# How to delete relation between two nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am unable to delete relation between two nodes. I am getting this result Returned 0 rows in 252 ms only. 
my query is:

```
MATCH (n: Company{ companyName : "Amagi Media Labs"})-[r: HAS_CUSTOMER]-(n: Company{ companyName : "IBN7"} ) delete r RETURN n,r;
```

How can I write this query.
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use different node identifiers for the two nodes you're matching, or it won't match either:

```
MATCH (n:Company {companyName:"Amagi Media Labs"})-[r:HAS_CUSTOMER]-(m:Company {companyName:"IBN7"})
DELETE r 
RETURN n,r;
```

Update: you can't return the relationship, so you'd only be able to `RETURN n, m` after the `DELETE`.

Comment: Can you return a deleted relationship though? I thought you'd get a `IllegalStateException` or something.